# Как установить imgaug на windows через pip?

Tags: python, pip

Устанавливаю через pip пакет imgaug. Выдаёт ошибку.

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: '...\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'......\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'...\\pip-install-3slq_kxq\\Shapely\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base '...\pip-install-3slq_kxq\Shapely\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: ...\pip-install-3slq_kxq\Shapely\
Complete output (9 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\pip-install-3slq_kxq\Shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
    from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
  File "...\pip-install-3slq_kxq\Shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
    lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
  File "...\python\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info 
Check the logs for full command output.
```

Что посоветуете делать?

P.s. все requirements установлены (согласно [документации](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/installation.html#installation-in-pip)), пробовал разные способы установки (см. документацию).

Comment: обновлять\пeрeустанавливать пробовали?

Comment: Вам необходимо 1. Проверить версии pip, и посмотреть pip list. 2. Посмотреть пути, которые использует pip, и версии python. 3. Потанцевать немного с бубном и добавить информации в вопрос.

Comment: И обновлял, и версию pip проверял, и пути пересмотрел. С бубном не танцевал, информации больше особо и нет :)

Comment: Разве что могу сказать, что пытаюсь разобраться с решением на kaggle - https://www.kaggle.com/aakashnain/beating-everything-with-depthwise-convolution.

Comment: geos_c.dll положи там где питон её увидит

Answer (score 1):

`pip` не может установить `shapely`. Для его установки похоже нужно предварительно установить [osgeo4w](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w#QuickStartforOSGeo4WUsers) или [geos](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos#Binaries)

Посмотри в пакете, возможно `geos_c.dll` лежит рядом, но не той архитектуры. например 32битная на 64битном питоне.